# importing python modules into another directory

Tags: python, python-import, ros

I have a ROS package that I am working with and I am trying to import a python module from another directory in the same package. My file structure is the follow:

```
package/
   src/
      __init__.py
      lab03/
        map_helper.py
        __init__.py
      lab04/
        foo.py
        __init__.py
```

I want to use `helper.py` in `foo.py`

`foo.py`

```
from src.lab03 import map_helper as helper
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
from src.lab03 import map_helper as helper ImportError: No module named src.lab03
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `package` directory to your sys path to be able to import packages

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../../../package')

from src.lab03 import map_helper as helper
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

`from package.src.lab03 import map_helper as helper`